# Android Shell commands execution at boot

Tags: android, root

In an Android app I'm trying to develop the app runs some shell commands at boot running commands through two functions inside a Receiver `onReceive()` method , but I have two issues:

1. The first function executes three separated commands with three calls of `executeCommand()`, but since in the code of my `executeCommand()` function is included `Process.waitFor()`, something in the receiver times out and doesn't always execute all the commands.
2. The second function commands should execute after the three previous shell commands are executed and return a result, and this doesn't happen. If I remove the `Process.waitFor()` all the commands are executed, but since the first commands haven't returned a result yet, they act wrong.

Is there a way to extend wait time? Running one only succession of commands instead of three separated commands would reduce the total time of `Process.waitFor()` ?

Comment: The documentation specifically says that you should *not* execute long-running commands on the main-thread of an onReceive call. You ought to create an `IntentService` to handle the shell commands and execute them in order. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)

Comment: This solved my problem, if you'll make an answer i'll be glad to accept it. Thank you, I missed those lines.

Comment: Glad I could help. I expanded it a little; it could help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BroadcastReceiver documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) specifically advises against executing long-running commands on the main-thread of the `onReceive()` invocation. A better solution would be to create an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to handle the shell commands and execute them in order. This won't block the `BroadcastReceiver` and should even increase boot speed.